Issue with Redirect URI in Next.js 14 & NextAuth V5 on Digital Ocean App Platform
I'm encountering a redirect issue after deploying my Next.js 14 app with NextAuth V5 to the Digital Ocean App Platform. The app uses Google OAuth for authentication, and while the Google part seems to work (as it tries to redirect back after a successful login), it redirects to https://localhost:3000 instead of my domain.
For additional context, the app works fine on localhost:3000 using a reverse proxy setup. This configuration also works in my local environment with Nginx as the reverse proxy.
I'm looking for advice on how to ensure the redirect points to the correct domain post-authentication.

Just use AUTH_URL={YOUR_DOMAIN} on your ENV variable. That should solve the problem. I have encountered the same problem. That gives me the solution.
